# Install PHP 5.5.9 and Apache2 mod

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, apt, php-5.5

I just updated an old server to Ubuntu 16.04 and my PHP got updated to 7.* and I'm struggling with the reinstallation of PHP 5.5.9, the one that my /var/www php code is written for.

I have tried adding the ppa `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` to my apt repository but it seems like only php5.6 available in this solution proposed everywhere on stackoverflow.

I need both the php 5.5.9 installation and the apache2 mod for this version of php. I know I should update the code but this is a big messy system and I need this workaround in the short term.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: C'mon, really? 5.5 doesn't even get security fixes any more since over a year ago ... If this is not some local test system, but connected to the internet - then do the sensible and responsible thing, and at least make your old stuff work under 5.6 http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: I do agree with you, it has to ! I am working on adapting the code as we discuss. The problem is, the software is unavailable to the customer while it has migration bugs.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work under 5.6, that worked under 5.5.9? http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.0 seems to be mostly bugfixes and improvements, does any of that actually hinder your app? Or is the reasoning rather general distrust when you did not extensively test against 5.6?

Comment: I would say general distrust. The code has been written in 2004 (php 4 originally), is a total procedural mess because it was maintained by unprofessionnal people. For now, the default encoding was changed to UTF8. But the system is disorganised and handling the encoding manually in each script. It is also breaking the handling of HTTP POST which were handled by $HTTP_POST_VARS but a nice quick workaround is to do $HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST;

Comment: Hi, the only solution I see is compiling your own.  What ever is available through apt is going to be to high a version for your needs, or will not link properly for your need.  Are you ok doing that?  I am pretty sure you can download the old versions you need.  Just setup apr, apr-util, apr-iconv, apache, openssl (?), php in some /opt/... directories and run it there.  Let me know if you need an example, I just did it on a server at work (recent versions, but it will show you how to do it).

Comment: Well if it was written in 2004, for PHP 4 - then unless the project comes close to nuclear launch codes-sensibility, I would maybe hazard a bet that switching from 5.5.9 to 5.6 is in all likelihood not going to blow the whole thing to smithereens now ... The alternative would be that you compile PHP 5.5.9 yourself.